# URL problems with framework created with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, url, hyperlink

I have recently purchased a book my Michael Peacock on PHP5 to further my understanding, however I seem to have hit a brick wall. When I click on the register link I am just sent to 404 page saying "The requested URL /authenticate/register was not found on this server." However I have followed the book through to this point and I am stumped to the problem.

My site URL which I am testing this on is: http://sportsnetuk.co.uk/

And it is set in index page.

Sorry about that I was unsure how to show the code so my code is available in a zip below, thanks for the help. The only thing missing from these files is the connection to my database which I already have

http://sportsnetuk.co.uk/views/default/images/files.html

Comment: We need to see code to see what is wrong

Comment: How about adding your code as code and not an image? makes it easier to manipulate to give you a good answer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and your first question!

Comment: Can you not post your php code you used?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your index.php is set up, in order to do  "friendly url" you need to have a .htaccess file

You can find an [example here](http://www.edinteractive.co.uk/article/?id=48)  on how you can achieve that

Check your server error log. As i see, you are on media temple, it's easy to check in the control panel

Based on what the error log says, if you don't have .htaccess, create one

If you have .htaccess, check if it has the correct permissions set up to it, and if it works properly for the framework

Comment: Also just I'm just looking at the logs now thank you